# Error during making video of extracted frames

Tags: python, image, opencv, video, frame

I extracted the video frames into a folder called "images". Let's consider:

a0.jpg
a1.jpg
a2.jpg
a3.jpg
and ......

now I want to make a video of those frames.

I have got this code to create video from extracted videos

```
  import cv2
import os


image_folder = 'images'
video_name = 'video.avi'


images = [img for img in os.listdir(image_folder) if img.endswith(".jpg")]
for i in range(len(images)):
    image_name = 'a' + str(i) + '.jpg'
    frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))

    height, width, layers = frame.shape

    video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, 0, 1, (width, height))

    video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, image_name)))
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

The problem is when I am making the video,  I get the video but the frames are ordered randomly, how can I arrange them in sequential order? thanks for the post How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you print the value of images and show how the names of images.

Comment: How do you mean exactly? they are all extracted from one video and they are all same size, the names are  a0.jpg, a1.jpg, a2.jpg, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated that your frames are not in order so that means when you are obtaining them via `os.listdir` they are not coming in order. You also stated that their names are like a0, a1 and so on so you can do this:

```
images = [img for img in os.listdir(image_folder) if img.endswith(".jpg")]
for i in range(len(images)):
    image_name = 'a' + str(i) + '.jpg'
    video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, image_name)))
```

**EDIT**

You placed your video writer inside the loop so it is being recreated every time. I have attached the complete code this time which should work.

```
import cv2
import os

image_folder = 'images'
video_name = 'video.avi'

images = [img for img in os.listdir(image_folder) if img.endswith(".jpg")]

frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
height, width, layers = frame.shape
video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, 0, 1, (width, height))

for i in range(len(images)):
    image_name = 'a' + str(i) + '.jpg'
    video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, image_name)))

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

Comment: I modified the code(see my post). But now the problem is that it does not play saved video. how can I fix that?

Comment: I have placed an edit section in my post. Check if it solves your problem now.

Comment: sorry but still does not work, the video is not playable.